# Types of solutions of ODEs and periodic orbits.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am currently studying specific types of solutions of ordinary differential equations. If a vector field can be autonomous or non-autonomous, in which of these cases are there periodic orbits if there are no equilibrium points? I'm struggling to understand this. (I am assuming the vector field is on the real numbers

Comment: I'm no specialist, but for non-autonomous systems it is definitely possible to have periodic orbits without stationary points. Consider a simple linear system $\dot{x}=-x + sin(t)$. The system clearly has no stationary points but does have a periodic orbit. A would love to get an answer for autonomous systems though.

Comment: @dmytro is there not a stationary point when x=sin(t)?

Comment: well, no. There's $t$ there, so the point already not stationary, i.e. the location where $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ is time-varying. This means that if one starts at that point, the derivative will become nonzero no matter what and the system will deviate from that point. The idea behind the stationary point is that if you start there - you stay there forever

Comment: @dmytro excuse my stupidity! Do you have any suggestions for the autonomous case? I believe that as there is no $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)=0$ then there is not an $x_1=x(t)=x(t+T)$ satisfying the definition of periodic orbit. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a feeling that it also depends on the dimension of the system, as it is a known fact that there's no chaos possible in a 2D system, and it is quite possible for $n>2$. It doesn't look like you can get away with a limit cycle but not stat. points in an autonomous 2D system. I might be mistaken though. Sorry for not really helping

Comment: I asked a friend of mine. As I said, for 2D autonomous systems the MUST be a fixed point if there's a limit cycle. In higher dimensions - it might and might not. This is can be shown by looking at the Divergence theorem in 2D. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this question can be answered in the following way,
If we have an autonomous vector field *f(x)* with no equilibrium points, then we see *f(x)* is larger than 0 or smaller than 0 for all x, and *f(x)* will be decreasing or increasing for all x, so depending what your vector field is defined on depends on whether a periodic orbit can exist, for the vector field defined on the **Real Line** then you will move away from whatever point you start at and will never return so periodic orbits are impossible, if however you are defined on a **Circle** then you will be constantly moving away from your point and so will return to your starting point wherever you start, hence all orbits defined on a circle are periodic in this case.
non autonomous can have periodic orbits proved by example